# SharePoint 2010 Workflows are still marked as InProgress

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I have a workflow which triggers an approval workflow. In some cases, the approval workflow is being approved/reject but my workflow is not set as completed and it remains as in progress.

Using the ULS Viewer, I noticed that I have an error

> WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow.

The current environment has SharePoint 2010 Workflows installed on SharePoint 2013.

What should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: When you see the WinWF error, always verify that your workflow is not running into NULL values.

Comment: @RohitWaghela I went through the errors and I noticed the following two errors which may be related:

1) Loading and running the event receiver class MyEventReceiver failed. Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: section
_____________

2) Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: section ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x81020089</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Value cannot be null.